# How to make an Excel macro run when the file is updated?

Tags: excel, vba, powerapps

I have a PowerApp which updates a cell in an Excel file hosted in OneDrive. The Excel file contains a macro that is supposed to run when the PowerApp changes the Excel file. However, it doesn't do that. If I update a cell manually, the macro works just fine. It's just not activated when the file is updated by PowerApps.

Is there a different function I can use that will be triggered when PowerApp changes the file?

If that is not possible, could I use a Flow to activate the macro?

Here is the current script that works with manual changes, but not the automatic PowerApps changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call InsertImageTest
End Sub
```

Here is the macro that I want to trigger using the code above.

```
Sub InsertImageTest()

' This macro inserts an image from a set location to a set cell.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imagePath As String
Dim cell As String
Dim posText As String
Dim imgLeft As Double
Dim imgTop As Double
Dim rngX As Range
Dim activeSheetName As String

' Customizable variables
imagePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Range("$B$2").Value
posText = "Signature"
activeSheetName = "Data" ' Set to "Data" by default, but will change to the Active sheets name, if the active sheet is not called "Data"

' For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
'    If CStr(Sheets(i).Name) Is CStr(activeSheetName) Then
'        Debug.Print "Code can be executed! Data tab was found"
'    End If
' Next i

cell = "$A$1"

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngX = Worksheets(activeSheetName).Range("A1:Z1000").Find(posText, lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    cell = rngX.Address
    Debug.Print cell
    Debug.Print rngX.Address & " cheating"
    Worksheets(activeSheetName).Range(cell).Value = ""

    Debug.Print rngX.Address & " real"

    imgLeft = Range(cell).Left
    imgTop = Range(cell).Top

    ' Width & Height = -1 means keep original size
    ws.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:=imagePath, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=imgLeft, _
    Top:=imgTop, _
    Width:=-1, _
    Height:=-1
End If

' The code beaneath will resize the cell to fit the picture
For Each Picture In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
PictureTop = Picture.Top
PictureLeft = Picture.Left
PictureHeight = Picture.Height
PictureWidth = Picture.Width
For N = 2 To 256
If Columns(N).Left > PictureLeft Then
PictureColumn = N - 1
Exit For
End If
Next N
For N = 2 To 65536
If Rows(N).Top > PictureTop Then
PictureRow = N - 1
Exit For
End If
Next N
Rows(PictureRow).RowHeight = PictureHeight
Columns(PictureColumn).ColumnWidth = PictureWidth * (54.29 / 288)
Picture.Top = Cells(PictureRow, PictureColumn).Top
Picture.Left = Cells(PictureRow, PictureColumn).Left
Next Picture

End Sub
```

Comment: Try the `Worksheet_Calculate` event handler.

Comment: @Dean Didn't work unfortunately. I'm only updating a string cell value, so Calculate is not called.

Comment: PowerApp opens the file and changes it?

Comment: It's not clear how PowerApps manipulates the data in the cell. Is the workbook *open* when you are manipulating it with PowerApps?

Comment: @DavidZemens PowerApps edits the workbook through an API, so it is not open when manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the server opens Excel through APIs and Excel doesn't fire macros in this way. It seems flow has [the same](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/Run-Macros-in-Excel/idi-p/171034). I would consider implement the macro function logic in PowerApps. Customize the edit form of the column which supposes to trigger the macro, depends what the macro should do. Possibly unlock a data card if the macro trys to alter a value of another column.

Comment: How could I implement the macro function logic in PowerApps? The app currently edits a form. This updates a table in Excel which contains all the file locations. All the cells should be unlocked. The macros job is to use the file location in the table to place the raw image in a cell. I've added the macro code for clarification.